# Changing legend title position in ggplot 2

Tags: r

Please can someone help? I am trying to move the legend title to the top and not on the same line with the legend. I have tried the code below

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: sunday you miss the code. Also, please post a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

If using ggplot, you could use arguments in the guides function

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(iris, 
       aes(x = Species, 
       y = Sepal.Width, 
       color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.position = 'top') +
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = "Legend Title On Top of Legend", title.position = "top"))
```

[image: sample]